# Laravel 4 form builder creating 'list' attribute input

Tags: php, laravel, formbuilder

I'm trying to use the form builder to create the following  line of code:

```
<input type="text" list="book_type" id="b_type" name="book_type">
```

However, I have no idea how do create the **list** type.

And this won't work:

```
{{ Form::input('list', 'book_type' }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the HTML you provided:

```
{{ Form::text('book_type', null, array('id' => 'b_type', 'list' => 'book_type')) }}
```

The third parameter to the `text` method is an array of attributes to add to the `input` element. `list` is an attribute, so it is included. Also, the `id` is different than the `name`, so it needs to be specified in the attribute array, as well.

If you'd prefer to stick with the `input` method, the attribute array is the fourth parameter:

```
{{ Form::input('text', 'book_type', null, array('id' => 'b_type', 'list' => 'book_type')) }}
```